# VBA How to search multiple columns for specific value and return an offset cell to modify

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an inventory list for several characters. I'm trying to create an entry form above the list that will search the list for if a character by that name is already carrying that item. If they are, it should add 1 to the Quantity Column. If not, it should add the data entered to the bottom of the list

I've tried several different codes, but my main issue is that I don't know much. I've just started learning and I've gone based on what I can find. This is primary variants of the code I've used. Might be wrong.

```
Sub Test3()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Inventories")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Inventories")

    For i = 9 To 9
        If IsEmpty(ws.Range("A" & i)) Then
            Exit For
        End If

        For j = 12 To 50000
            If IsEmpty(ws2.Range("A" & j)) Then
                Exit For
            End If

            If ws.Range("A" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
                If ws.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("B" & j).Value Then

                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Finished ")
End Sub
```

The typical result is that it fails to give any result whatsoever with the values listed on my sheet here

[image: <https://imgur.com/a/tinjx7J>]

It should be testing cells A9&B9 to find a match below. So if spellbook is in B9, it should find Adrys in A20 and Spellbook in B20, then change the quantity in F20 and change it to 2 by adding 1 to the existing 1.

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in your loop. As soon as both conditions are met, you exit the loop. The `i` loop looks redundant anyway. More efficient to use the Find method to avoid looping through thousands of cells.

Comment: I think I understand the basics of what you are saying. However, I'm not entirely sure I understand how to utilize the find method in this context. Would this formula technically work for my purposes if I made a specific change somewhere in it? Example: putting something inside the loop that performs an action. An issue, however, is that I don't know how to select one of the found cells and offset from it to the right.

Comment: Alternatively, would this be a better piece of code: 
`With Sheets("Inventories").Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(1, 314))
    Dim Results As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    Set Results = Cells.Find(What = "A9")

        x = Results.Row
        y = Results.Column
End With` But even if it was, I still don't know how to make a cell selection offset from that result. (It's also returning the wrong cell, somehow)